# Non differentiable solutions to $\partial_x f + \partial_y f =0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, baire-category

[This nice paper](http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~cori/IREM/baire-godefroy.pdf) by Gilles Godefroy (in French) tells us the story of Baire's lemma. In 1896, Monsieur Baire was lecturing on analysis and carelessly gave the following exercise: to find all solutions to the differential equation 
$$\tag{1}
{\partial f \over \partial x} + {\partial f \over \partial y} =0.
$$
This is rather easy if $f$ is assumed to be differentiable, for in that case the equation can be rewritten as 
$$
{\partial f \over \partial \vec{v}}=0,\qquad \vec{v}=(1, 1),$$
where $\partial/\partial \vec{v}$ denotes directional derivative. From this one concludes that $$\tag{2}f(x, y)=\phi(x-y)$$ for an arbitrary differentiable function $\phi$ of one variable.

> But what if $f$ is not differentiable?

According to the paper, this train of thoughts led Baire to investigate the subject of *separately continuous* functions. Those are functions of two or more variables that are continuous if all variables minus one are held fixed. (Indeed, for equation (1) to hold, partial derivatives need at least exist, and so $f$ must be separately continuous). This is very interesting, but unfortunately the paper does *not* tell the end of the story about the differential equation! Hence the question.

> **Question**. Do there exist solutions to the equation (1) that are not of the form (2)?

Here a *solution* is a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ that admits partial derivatives with respect to both variables and that satisfies relation (1) at all points.

Comment: Is it separately continuous or separately derivable ?

Comment: What sort of boundary conditions are you considering imposing? For instance, if you impose the boundary conditions as an IVP, meaning that you specify $u(x_0,y)=v(y)$ for some function $v$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, then this is just the transport equation on $\mathbb{R}$. For the transport equation, it is known (cf. Evans, for instance) that all solutions have that form (even weak solutions!)

Comment: @marwalix: It is differentiable in both variables separately. (Maybe one can say "separately differentiable"?)

Comment: @Ian: Actually I don't care about boundary conditions, this is just a curiosity. I don't know if a solution in the present sense is also a weak solution: for this, one should be able to integrate by parts, hence one should have absolute continuity in each variable separately.  But the text only speaks of "existence of partial derivatives".